# usb_enable_autosuspend in runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

I have problematic modem connected to USB. I work on power consumption and I have to enable USB autosuspend after initialization of modem. If I do this after initialization there is problem, becuse autosuspend sometimes occurs after few times on/off display(after early suspend, because I use android), sometimes just after invoke usb_enable_autosuspend. I don't know why it doesn't work immediately. I am sure that modem don't send anything, so it should works. Maybe someone has this problem?

thanks for responses